# How to plot vectors in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I am trying to plot vectors in mathematica, some 2d and some 3d.

Is there a way to do this?

I Need the coordinate axes and an arrow head on a line basically.

Thanks,
Blake

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrow.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are some examples that I think are self-explanatory:

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-1, 1}}]}, Axes -> True]

Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, -1}}]}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look at these built in plots:

[StreamPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html) and [ListStreamPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListStreamPlot.html)

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

---

[StreamDensityPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamDensityPlot.html) and [ListStreamDensityPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListStreamDensityPlot.html)

[image]

---

[VectorPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorPlot.html) and [ListVectorPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListVectorPlot.html)

[image]

---

[VectorPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) and [ListVectorPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListVectorPlot3D.html)

[image]

Comment: Those are great and all, but I'd rarely use them. I need a good way to plot the columns of a matrix.